# What is the performance cost of the eager style in TFJS?

Tags: performance, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

The paper [TENSORFLOW.JS: MACHINE LEARNING FOR THE WEB AND BEYOND](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.05350) states:

> Since an important part of our design goals is to prioritize
>   ease-of-use over performance, TensorFlow.js supports the eager style
>   of differentiation.

In general what kind of performance hit are we talking about? Does it depend on the model? Are there cases where there is no performance difference at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main performance benefits of a declarative (a.k.a., deferred-execution, graph-mode) programming paradigm like the one in the default graph model of TensorFlow v1 (Python) comes from the following aspects:

- Pushing the entire model down to the C++ layer, where execution overhead is much
  lower compared to interpreted or non-compiled languages such as Python and
  JavaScript
- **Parallel execution** of independent paths of the model's computation graph. An
  example is a model consisting of a number of separate input towers. These
  towers can be executed concurrently on different cores of the CPU or multiple
  GPUs of the same host.
- Thanks to the fact that the entire model is known before the execution begins,
  the C++ execution engine can perform a whole suite of **optimizations on the
  model's computation graph**. Just to give a few examples:

  - **Constant folding**: a subtree of the graph consisting of only stateless, 
    deterministic operations on constant nodes can be folded into a single      constant node
  - **Op fusion**: in some cases, a few adjacent nodes (ops) of the computation
    graph can be replaced by a mathematically equivalent but computationally more
    efficient node.
  - **Pruning**: some computation graphs contain nodes that don't contribute to
    the final output. A graph-model execution engine can see that beforehand
    and prevent those nodes from executing.
- **Just in time (JIT) compilation**: the graph execution engine can take the
  entire graph and compile it to a lower-level representation that involves a lower
  dispatching overhead and are more amenable
  to high-performance execution on the available hardware (e.g., CUDA programs
  for NVIDIA or compatible GPUs, special instructions for Google TPUs, or
  even shader programs for WebGL, etc.)

All the aforementioned optimization are supported by graph-mode TensorFlow. For
more details, google for terms "grappler" and "XLA".

TensorFlow.js adopts an imperative (a.k.a., eager) paradigm, mainly based on
usability considerations. This is analogous to TensorFlow eager execution,
PyTorch and NumPy. As a result, it doesn't come with all the aforementioned
opportunities for optimization.

However, realize that there are ways to get computation graphs out from an
imperative program (see TensorFlow v2's tf.function decorator and [JAX](https://github.com/google/jax)). There is no reason why TensorFlow.js
can't adopt a similar paradigm for performance boosts. It's just the need hasn't
been clear enough for the product team to prioritize that feature yet.